# Preventing PostgreSQL from starting on boot in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 and it runs automatically when I start the system (Kubuntu).

How can I avoid this?

I need to start it manually, and I don't want it to start unattended because I need to look at the console.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Ubuntu or Debian can run multiple instances of PostgreSQL and provide a specific way to autostart/stop/start each cluster.

There should be a file named `start.conf` inside `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main` (or more generally /etc/postgresql/<*version*>/<*clustername*>) with these self-explanatory contents:

```
# Automatic startup configuration
# auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
# manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
#         pg_ctlcluster
# disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
#           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
#           accidents).

auto
```

If you replace *auto* by *manual*, you could start this PostgreSQL instance only when desired with the command:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.2 main start
```

As for looking at the console, what you should want instead is having this run in a terminal when you work with the database:

```
tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Short Term

The command `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d` is used to start, stop, enable, or disable services (i.e. remove System-V style init script links from /etc/init.d/).

Type `man update-rc.d` to familiarize yourself with the command and its parameters.

Here are some examples from the [update-rc.d ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety) manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/en/man8/update-rc.d.8.html):

```
update-rc.d -f foobar remove
update-rc.d foobar stop 20 2 3 4 5
```

Then type something along the lines of `sudo update-rc.d [service] disable` for any service listed in your /etc/init.d/ directory. That will prevent [service] from starting at boot. If you also want to shut down the service immediately, try `sudo service [service] stop`

#### Long Term

You probably *do not* need to run PostgreSQL manually in order to see its console output. You just need to *log* that output, and tail the log file.